# Playwright - how to switch to new tab and then to frame

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

I have below scenario -

1. Launch browser and do some operations
2. Click on a button, a new tab opens
3. switch to new tab.
4. In new tab, switch to iframe and perform
   operations inside frame.

How can I handle this in playwright? Once I switch to new tab, all elements are inside frame, so I want to switch to new frame after switching to new tab

Note - Frame doesn't have name. I can use xpath to identify frame.

will page.frame("xpath to iframe") work?

If anyone can provide small code snippet, would be really helpful.

I Tried using page.frame("xpath locator to iframe") - but not working

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to the new tab like [this](https://playwright.dev/docs/pages#handling-popups).

```
const [newTab] = await Promise.all([
  page.waitForEvent('popup'),
  page.locator('your locator here').click(),
]);

await newTab.waitForLoadState();
```